How do those 2 transformers work together to drive ultrasonic cleaner's piezo?
For a couple days I try to understand how the following ultrasonic driver circuit works. Possibly it drives a 40 kHz piezo. I reverse engineered and drew the circuit. There are lots of things that I need to understand but I don't have any tiny understanding of how those transformers are working together and why are they connected as such?


Have you tried to simulate it?

At a guess, it looks like a Royer converter.T1 drives the transistors and T2 is the output transformer.  C2 gives some phase shift .

@winny I haven't dared yet.

Please do. You will learn a lot.

@kemal I am not going to be of much use, having little to no applicable experience here, driving a piezo for this purpose. But can you write out what your existing work on this circuit has produced to move things along in the right direction?

@periblepsis Actually I am trying to start a repair business on biomedical and electronics stuff used in healthcare. I was recently sent a few ultrasonic cleaners to fix. Though I checked and verified all the components were working  after I powered the board transistors were blown most of the time. So I decided to dive deep as much as I could.

@kemal Good business to get into, I suppose. The customers can afford quality work. I've helped create some of the equipment used there -- infusion pumps, for example. But isn't there a way you can segue into this business by working for a time with someone else already in the business and who can train you, more quickly? Regardless, thanks. What you wrote about your goals will definitely help others trying to get a bead on what you really need.

@periblepsis thanks for your kind words.

@kemal You have my best wishes. I've been self-employed almost all my life. And I understand well the elements required to make all that work out over many decades of time. I can't tell you how many "employees" have asked me about what it takes. My usual response is that it cannot be for the money, but that you need some other very important reason for being there. Because if it is just for the money, then there will be times when being an employee pays better. And if you quit, to get the better money, then the business itself is instantly dead. So another reason to be there is required.

For oscillation startup R1, R2, C3, R3 and DB1 are used.
C3 will be charged positive via R1 on the left side, while R3 lets the charge current flow to the negative supply.
When the trigger voltage of the DIAC DB1 is reached across C3, the discharge current through BE of Q1 turns Q1 on and the emitter voltage quickly rises.
This rising voltage edge passes C4 and produces a rising current in the primary winding of transformer T1 (pin 2 to pin 1).
The voltage on the secondary side of T2 allows a current flow from pin 3 through the windings on the right side of transformer T1 and through C2 back to pin 4. A second path goes through the piezo capacitance.
Between pin 1 and pin 2 of T1 the voltage rises and allows the base current of Q1 to continue after the DIAC has discharged C3.
As the transformer T1 is drawn, the winding between pin 3 and 4 would as well produce a voltage, that turns on Q2. This would immediately destroy both transistors, they must never conduct at the same time.
So either there is a mistake in the schematic and pin 3 and 4 must be swapped or the transformer is constructed in a way that the lower left winding has a reverse turn direction. This would be marked with dots in a datasheet. I will assume swapped pins here.
When C4 is charged the current through the primary winding of T2 is falling, so is the current in the secondary path. The energy stored in C2 and the piezo now create a discharge current with reverse direction in the left side windings of T1.
The polarity of the voltages in the right side windings change now. The base-emitter voltage of Q1 becomes negative, Q1 will be off. Q2 will be turned on via C6 and the voltage at the left side of C4 is falling fast.
Again this produces a current in the primary side of T2, but with reverse direction now.
Each time C4 charge current drops, a polarity reversal in the secondary side will follow and the oscillation will continue.
R1 and R2 produce a DC bias with half of the supply voltage and the average voltage of the right side of C4 also is half of the supply voltage. So C3 never reaches the trigger voltage of the DIAC again.
Without a connected piezo or a broken piezo at the output, the resonance frequency of the circuit is incorrect and this may be critical to the circuit. The oscillation frequency may rise to values, where the transistors cannot follow and overheat.
